# jQuery calculating price if many elements on same page using same IDs?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have 12 of these forms on a page on each product. It allows someone to enter a quantity and have it calculate the price, but doesn't yet work. The new price should replace what's in the `orderprice` class div.

```
<form action="" method="post">

    <input type="number" id="amount-<?php echo $productId; ?>" class="orderamount" name="amount" value="1" min="1" max="2000" maxlength="4" />
    <input type="hidden" name="product" value="<?php echo $productId; ?>" readonly="readonly" disabled="disabled" />
    <div id="price-<?php echo $productId; ?>" class="orderprice">

        <?php
            echo html_entity_decode($currencyAlignCode) . round($productPrice * $currencyMultiplier, 2);
        ?>

    </div>
    <input type="submit" class="addcart" value="" name="order" /> 
</form>
```

I want to take the value of `amount-<?php echo $productId; ?>`, and automatically calculate the price by multiplying that value by `$productPrice` and again by `$currencyMultiplier`, and then add `html_entity_decode($currencyAlignCode)` in front of it.

I know how to do that if there were only 1 form on the page and I didn't need to account for `<?php echo $productId; ?>`. This is how I would do it for an individual form, but how can I do it for several? And each price would only grab the quantity from the associated input box?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#amount").bind('click keyup', function(event) {

        var amount = $("#amount").val();
        var productPrice = <?php echo $productPrice; ?>;
        var currencyMultiplier = <?php echo $currencyMultiplier; ?>;
        var currencyCode = <?php echo html_entity_decode($currencyAlignCode); ?>;

        var totalPrice = amount * productPrice * currencyMultiplier;

        $("#price").html('currencyCode' + totalPrice);

    });
});
```

This code will only do it for 1 product. I want the input from each to show in the respective price box.

Sorry if it's not clear, it was kind of hard to explain.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this? Use multiple selectors or grab the selectors that start with something.

```
  <input type="number" id="amount-<?php echo $productId; ?>" productPrice="<?php echo $productPrice; ?>" ...


$("[id^=amount]").each(function(index){
  $(this).bind("click key up", function(){
    var amount = $(this).val();
    var productPrice = $(this).attr('productPrice');
    ...
  });
});
```

https://api.jquery.com/each/

http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/

Comment: Thank you, but I don't think this is what I'm looking for. I need it to calculate it based on which input field the user types in. There will be hundreds in total, so I can't manually type out something like this for each.

Comment: Type this JS code out for each you mean? I agree. You can place the php values of that form inside custom attributes and later retrieve them through jquery rather than printing them out directly into the jquery function.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing some extensive Googling and coming up with the solution.

I use attr to grab the id based on the changed class.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".orderamount").bind('click keyup', function(event) {



        var productId = $(this).attr('id');
        var setId = productId.substring(7);

        var amount = $('#amount-' + setId).val();
        var productPrice = <?php echo $productPrice; ?>;
        var currencyMultiplier = <?php echo $currencyMultiplier; ?>;
        var currencyCode = <?php echo html_entity_decode($currencyAlignCode); ?>;


        var totalPrice = round(amount * productPrice * currencyMultiplier, 2);

        $('#price-' + setId).html('currencyCode' + totalPrice);


    });
});
```